# How to add hint to text box

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I would like to add a hint value to my text box. It should look like this-

[image: hint value]

(like- "Enter your comments" in the picture, when there is nothing wroth on the field I want to be hint there)

my code-

```
  field = 'UserName'
  row = Frame(root)
  lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
  ent = Entry(row)
  row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
  lab.pack(side=LEFT)
  ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
```

how can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple you should add a default value for it.

```
  field = 'UserName'
  row = Frame(root)
  lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
  ent = Entry(row)


  ent.insert(0, 'Your default value here...')


  row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
  lab.pack(side=LEFT)
  ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
```

Comment: thanks but I want it to be at the background, not like default text, more like hint/ title

Comment: You have to make a mouse click event so when the user clicks on it, the default value disappears and text color changes to black.

Comment: How I make mouse click event?

Answer (score 0):

So, as you must have realised by now, there is no placeholder/hint attribute. You can only emulate the feature by using default values and mouse click events.

if you want the default text to look like placeholder, make necessary styling adjustments. Eg: You can color the text with color: #b3b3b3;

I know its a hack, but this is the only way I can think of.